# Is my routing good or bad? in PHP

Tags: php

I just want to checking if this kind of routing is good or bad?

I implement the routing of my web appl to something like this.

All page will be pointing to the index.php

in index.php I have this code

```
$url = array_values(array_filter( explode( '/', strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) ) ) ); 
switch( $url[0] ) {
    case "admin"    : {
        if( !$this->us->isAdmin ) {
            $this->GoToLoginPage();
        }
        array_shift( $uri );
        $department = new Admin( $uri );
    } break;
    case "article"  : {
        if( count( $uri ) == 2 ) {
            displayArticle( $uri[1] );
        }
        else {
            displayError();
        }
    } break;
    default : {
        displayIndex();
    } break;
}
```

I just want to know is there any pro and con of doing something like this.

Comment: I would separate the logic and the site specific functionality.

Comment: What your mean by separate logic and site specific functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate your logic and site specific functionality like this:

```
function Router{
    $url = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]))));
    switch($url[0]){
        case "admin": $this->Admin($url);
            break;
        case "article": $this->Article($url);
            break;
        default: displayIndex();
    }
}

function Admin($uri){
    if( !$this->us->isAdmin ) {
        $this->GoToLoginPage();
    }
    array_shift( $uri );
    $department = new Admin( $uri );
}

function Article($uri){
    if( count( $uri ) == 2 ) {
        displayArticle( $uri[1] );
    } else {
        displayError();
    }
}
```

It's much cleaner, and easier to update.